Distribution of Event Times in a Poisson Process?
I am trying to learn how to prove the following: if we know $k$ events occurred in a Poisson process between times $t_1$ and $t_2$, the exact times of these events are uniformly distributed. Normally, everyone talks about the distribution of interarrival times in a Poisson Process are Exponential ... but what about the distribution of the actual event times?  I tried to show this below.
In a Poisson process, the number of events $N(t)$ in an interval ($0$, $t$) follows a Poisson distribution with parameter $λt$:
$$ P(N(t) = k) = \frac{(λt)^k e^{-λt}}{k!} $$
The probability of exactly $k$ events occurring in ($t₁, t₂$) is:
$$ P(N(t_2 - t_1) = k) = \frac{(λ(t_2 - t_1))^k e^{-λ(t_2 - t_1)}}{k!} $$
Let's say that these $k$ events happen at times $t_1, t_2, ...t_k$. Then, the probability of observing an exact sequence of $k$ events at a specific set of times in a specific order is given by:
$$ f(t_1, t_2, ..., t_k | N(t_1, t_2) = k) = \frac{k!}{(t_2 - t_1)^k} $$
I was given this hint by my professor on defining a new variable $u_i$ that is based on the event times:
$$ u_i = \frac{t_i - t_1}{t_2 - t_1} \quad \text{for } i = 1, 2, ..., k $$
We can see that the maximum value of  $u_i$ is 1 . And this only happens when the final event (i.e $k^{th}$ event) happens at time $t_2$.
The Jacobian matrix is defined as:
$$ J = \begin{bmatrix}
   \frac{\partial t_1}{\partial u_1} & \frac{\partial t_1}{\partial u_2} & \cdots & \frac{\partial t_1}{\partial u_k} \\
   \frac{\partial t_2}{\partial u_1} & \frac{\partial t_2}{\partial u_2} & \cdots & \frac{\partial t_2}{\partial u_k} \\
   \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
   \frac{\partial t_k}{\partial u_1} & \frac{\partial t_k}{\partial u_2} & \cdots & \frac{\partial t_k}{\partial u_k}
   \end{bmatrix} $$
Express $tᵢ$ in terms of $uᵢ$:
$$ t_i = t_1 + (t_2 - t_1)u_i $$
Evaluate the partial derivatives:
$$ \frac{\partial t_i}{\partial u_j} = \begin{cases}
   t_2 - t_1 & \text{if } i = j \\
   0 & \text{if } i \neq j
   \end{cases} $$
The Jacobian matrix is diagonal:
$$ J = \begin{bmatrix}
   t_2 - t_1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
   0 & t_2 - t_1 & \cdots & 0 \\
   \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
   0 & 0 & \cdots & t_2 - t_1
   \end{bmatrix} $$
The determinant of a diagonal matrix is the product of its diagonal elements:
$$ |J| = (t_2 - t_1)^k $$
Therefore:
$$  |J| =  \left|\frac{\partial(t_1, ..., t_k)}{\partial(u_1, ..., u_k)}\right| = (t_2 - t_1)^k $$
From here, we need to use the Change of Variable Rule to demonstrate that $u_i$ follows a Uniform Distribution. That is, we wan to show the joint distribution $ f_U(u_1, ..., u_k)$ is uniform.
We know the general change of variable rule:
$$ f_Y(y) = f_X(g^{-1}(y)) \cdot \left|\frac{d}{dy}g^{-1}(y)\right| $$
We know the original density function:
$$ f_T(t_1, ..., t_k) = \frac{k!}{(t_2 - t_1)^k} $$
$$ t_i = t_1 + (t_2 - t_1)u_i $$
As a formality, we can say that:
$$t_i = g(u_i)$$
$$u_i = g^{-1}(t_i)$$
$$g^{-1}(u_i) = t_i$$
Back to the change of variable rule:
$$f(u_i) = f(t_i) \left( \frac{dt_i}{du_i} \right)$$
$$f(u_i) = f(t_i) \frac{d}{du_i} g^{-1}(u_i) = f(t_i) \frac{d}{du_i} \cdot t_i $$
Above, we showed that $\frac{d}{du_i} \cdot t_i = J$ and that $J = (t_2 - t_1)^k $ . Thus, we can finally show that:
$$ f_U(u_1, ..., u_k) = \frac{k!}{(t_2 - t_1)^k} \cdot (t_2 - t_1)^k $$
$$ f_U(u_1, ..., u_k) = k! $$
Therefore, the resulting density function  is constant and equal to $k!$. And this only happens for a Uniform Random Variable. Thus, in a Poisson Process, the actual times of the events are uniformly distributed ... even though the interarrival times are exponentially distributed.
Did I show this correctly?

I tried to write some supporting "proofs" below:

Note 1: Proof that interarrival times in a Poisson process are exponential :

Let $T$ be the time until the first event occurs in a Poisson process with rate $λ$:
$$ P(T > t) = P(N(t) = 0) = \frac{(λt)^0 e^{-λt}}{0!} = e^{-λt} $$
The cumulative distribution function (CDF) of T:
$$ F_T(t) = P(T ≤ t) = 1 - P(T > t) = 1 - e^{-λt} $$
To find the probability density function (PDF), we differentiate the CDF:
$$ f_T(t) = \frac{d}{dt}F_T(t) = \frac{d}{dt}(1 - e^{-λt}) = λe^{-λt} $$
This is the PDF of an exponential distribution with rate parameter $λ$.
The interarrival times between any two consecutive events, we can use the memoryless property of the Poisson process. This property states that the time until the next event is independent of how long it's been since the last event. Let $T₁$ be the time until the first event, and $T₂$ be the time between the first and second events. For any $s$, $t > 0$:
$$ P(T₂ > t | T₁ = s) = P(T₂ > t) = e^{-λt} $$
We can see that $T₂$ has the same distribution as $T₁$
I think we can extend this to all interarrival times $Tₖ$:
$$ P(T_k > t) = e^{-λt} $$
$$ f_{T_k}(t) = λe^{-λt} $$

Note 2: The Exponential Distribution follows the memoryless property

A random variable $X$ is said to have the memoryless property if, for any positive real numbers $s$ and $t$:
$$P(X > s + t | X > s) = P(X > t)$$
We can see that if $X$ be an exponentially distributed random variable, it will follow the memoryless property. The probability density function and the cumulative density function for $X$ is:
$$f(x) = λe^{-λx}, x ≥ 0$$
$$F(x) = 1 - e^{-λx}, x ≥ 0$$
To prove the memoryless property, we need to show that:
$$P(X > s + t | X > s) = P(X > t)$$
LHS:
$$\begin{aligned}
P(X > s + t | X > s) &= \frac{P(X > s + t \text{ and } X > s)}{P(X > s)} 
&= \frac{P(X > s + t)}{P(X > s)} 
&= \frac{1 - F(s + t)}{1 - F(s)} 
&= \frac{1 - (1 - e^{-λ(s+t)})}{1 - (1 - e^{-λs})} 
&= \frac{e^{-λ(s+t)}}{e^{-λs}} 
&= e^{-λt}
\end{aligned}$$
RHS:
$$\begin{aligned}
P(X > t) &= 1 - F(t) 
&= 1 - (1 - e^{-λt}) 
&= e^{-λt}
\end{aligned}$$
We can see both sides of the equation are equal to $e^{-λt}$, thus proving:
$$P(X > s + t | X > s) = P(X > t)$$
Therefore, the exponential distribution satisfies the memoryless property.

Note 3: The joint distribution of $k$ uniform variables

For a single uniform random variable $X$ on the interval (0, T):
$$ f_X(x) = \begin{cases} 
   \frac{1}{T} & \text{for } 0 < x < T \\
   0 & \text{otherwise}
   \end{cases} $$
Now, consider $k$ independent uniform random variables $U₁, U₂, ..., Uₖ$, each on ($0$, $T$).
Because these variables are independent, their joint probability density function is the product of their individual PDFs. Thus, for any given point ($u₁, ..., uₖ$) where $0 < uᵢ < T$ for all $i$, the joint density is:
$$ \begin{align}
   f_U(u_1, ..., u_k) &= f_{U_1}(u_1) \cdot f_{U_2}(u_2) \cdot ... \cdot f_{U_k}(u_k) \\
   &= \frac{1}{T} \cdot \frac{1}{T} \cdot ... \cdot \frac{1}{T} \quad \text{(k times)} \\
   &= \left(\frac{1}{T}\right)^k \\
   &= \frac{1}{T^k}
   \end{align} $$
While I am really week in geometry, I think this is referring to a k-dimensional hypercube $(0, T)ᵏ$. Outside this hypercube (i.e., if any $uᵢ$ is not between $0$ and $T$), the joint density is zero, because at least one of the individual densities would be zero. Therefore:
$$ f_U(u_1, ..., u_k) = \begin{cases} 
\frac{1}{T^k} & \text{for } 0 < u_i < T, \, i = 1, ..., k \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases} $$
We can finally verify that:
$$ \int_0^T \int_0^T ... \int_0^T \frac{1}{T^k} du_1 du_2 ... du_k = 1 $$
$$ \int_0^T \int_0^T ... \int_0^T \frac{1}{T^k} du_1 du_2 ... du_k = 1 $$
$$ \frac{1}{T^k} \int_0^T \int_0^T ... \int_0^T du_1 du_2 ... du_k = 1 $$
$$ \int_0^T du_k = T $$
$$ \frac{1}{T^k} \cdot T \int_0^T \int_0^T ... \int_0^T du_1 du_2 ... du_{k-1} = 1 $$
$$ \frac{1}{T^k} \cdot T \cdot T \cdot ... \cdot T \, \, (\text{k times}) = 1 $$
$$ \frac{1}{T^k} \cdot T^k = 1 $$
$$ \int_0^T \int_0^T ... \int_0^T \frac{1}{T^k} du_1 du_2 ... du_k = 1 $$
To account for all possible orderings that could result in this particular ordered sequence, we need to multiply by $k!$:
$$  f_U(u_1, ..., u_k) =  k! \cdot \frac{1}{T^k} $$

Note 4: Definition for the Change of Variable Rule

If $X$ is a univariate continuous random variable with probability density function $f_X(x)$, and given some function $Y = g(X)$. Then, the probability density function of $Y$ is given by ($g^(-1)$ is the inverse function of $g$):
$$ f_Y(y) = f_X(g^{-1}(y)) \cdot \left|\frac{d}{dy}g^{-1}(y)\right| $$
If $X = (X₁, ..., Xₙ)$ is a multivariate continuous random vector with joint probability density function $f_X(x₁, ..., xₙ)$, and for some $Y$:
$$ Y_i = g_i(X_1, ..., X_n) \quad \text{for } i = 1, ..., n $$
Then, the joint probability density function of Y is given by (uses the Jacobian):
$$ f_Y(y_1, ..., y_n) = f_X(h_1(y), ..., h_n(y)) \cdot |J| $$
Where $(h₁, ..., hₙ)$ is the inverse transformation of $(g₁, ..., gₙ)$

Your proof is confusing because you are using $t_1$ and $t_2$ to denote the bounds of the interval, and to also denote the times of the first two jumps in that interval. Can you amend your question to address that?

I think this "proof" is way too much. The memoryless property states that no interval is more likely than another with the same length to have an event and that probability of an event does not depend on past or future events. This is more than enough to prove that, given the number of events, the time distribution of those events in the interval is uniform.

I cannot follow this proof. "We know the original density function $$f_T(t_1, ..., t_k) = \frac{k!}{(t2 - t1)^k},.$$ How? If you use that to show something about $u_i$ what does it prove?

@ Wei: thank you for your feedback, I will address this soon

@ Nicola: thanks for the feedback, after reading your comment - I fully agree with you and think I made a "mountain out of a molehill"

@ Kurt: there is a typo there, it should be $t_2 - t_1$

@ Kurt: I tried to define a new variable $U_i$ based on the actual event times ... and the show that $U_i$ is indeed uniform.

The probability distribution $f(t_1,...., t_k)$ is like an order statistic, derived using first principles/combinatorics

Partial Answer
Denote by $\tau_n$ the $n$-th jump time of the Poisson process $N\,.$
Conditional on $\tau_n$ being the only jump time in the fixed interval $[t,T]$ it is uniformly distributed there.
Proof. We have to calculate
$$\tag1
\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\mathbb P\Big\{\tau_n\in[t,s]\Big|N_t=n-1,N_T-N_t=1\Big\}
=\frac{\mathbb P\big\{\tau_n\in[t,s],N_t=n-1,N_T-N_t=1\big\}}{\mathbb P\big\{N_t=n-1\,,N_T-N_t=1\big\}}\,.
$$
The probability in the denominator of (1) is
\begin{align}\tag2
&\mathbb P\Big\{N_t=n-1,N_T-N_t=1,\tau_n\in[t,s]\Big\}\\[2mm]
&=\mathbb P\Big\{N_t=n-1,N_T-N_t=1,N_s-N_t=1\Big\}\tag3\\[2mm]
&=\mathbb P\Big\{N_t=n-1,N_s-N_t=1,N_T-N_s=0\Big\}\tag4\\[2mm]
&=\underbrace{\mathbb P\big\{N_t=n-1\big\}}_{(*)}\underbrace{\mathbb P\big\{N_s-N_t=1\big\}}_{(**)}\underbrace{\mathbb P\big\{N_T-N_s=0\big\}}_{(***)}\tag5\\[2mm]
&=\underbrace{\frac{(\lambda t)^{n-1}e^{-\lambda t}}{(n-1)!}}_{(*)}\underbrace{\lambda(s-t)\,e^{-\lambda(s-t)}}_{(**)}\,\underbrace{e^{-\lambda(T-s)}}_{(***)}=
\frac{(\lambda t)^{n-1}e^{-\lambda t}}{(n-1)!}\lambda(s-t)\,e^{-\lambda(T-t)}\,\tag6
\end{align}
where the equals sign leading to (5) holds due to the independence of the increments of $N\,.$
The probability in the numerator of (1) is
\begin{align}\tag7
&\mathbb P\Big\{N_t=n-1,N_T-N_t=1\Big\}=
\frac{(\lambda t)^{n-1}e^{-\lambda t}}{(n-1)!}\lambda(T-t)\,e^{-\lambda(T-t)}
\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align}\tag8
\mathbb P\Big\{\tau_n\in[t,s]\,\Big|N_t=n-1\,,N_T-N_t=1\Big\}
=\frac {s-t}{T-t}\,.
\end{align}
$$\tag*{$\Box$}
\phantom.
$$

@ Kurt: Thank you for this! Just a question - why did you call this a "partial answer"? In my opinion, what you have written is a full answer?

Just to clarify, your proof shows that the probability distribution of the nth jump time occurring between times (t,s) only depends on (s,t,T) .... and this property can only happen in a Uniform Distribution (by definition). Have I understood this correctly?

@farrow90 maybe it is not only a full answer but also a clarification of what you wanted to prove. Apart from the notational issues that Wei mentioned already I find the expression  $f(t_1, t_2, ..., t_k | N(t_1, t_2) = k) = \frac{k!}{(t_2 - t_1)^k}$ quite confusing. Edit: yes you understood this answer correctly.

@ Kurt: thanks for everything ... I am trying to self-study aspects of the poisson distribution, e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4968239/probability-of-1-event-in-a-small-amount-of-time  . Can you please take a look at this if you have time and let me know if the math makes sense to you? thank you so much
