Probability of 1 Event in a Small Amount of Time?
Consider the following question: Given that $\lambda$ events are expected to happen in each unit of time, what is the probability of 1 event happening in some small amount $\Delta t$ unit of time?
Normally, this question can be answered relatively straightforward using the Poisson Distribution. However, I am specifically trying to answer this question WITHOUT using the Poisson Distribution.
Part 1: I started by defining a generic CDF $F(t)$, this is the the CDF of the time until the next event occurs. This means that:
$$F(t) = P(\text{an event occurs by time } t)$$
Logically, the complement of this is the probability that no event occurs by time $t$:
$$P(\text{no event by time } t) = 1 - F(t)$$
Part 2: The next part relies on a mathematical assumption (see second link in the reference) that $\lambda$ events are more likely to happen in larger periods of times compared to lesser periods of time. This idea is naturally encapsulated within the exponential decay function (note the relationship with the differential equation):
$$\frac{d}{dt}P(\text{no event by time } t) = -\lambda P(\text{no event by time } t)$$
$$P(\text{no event by time } t) = Ce^{-\lambda t} $$
In terms of constraints, we know that at $t=0$, the probability of no event is 1, so:
$$P(\text{no event by time } 0) = C = 1$$
Via further substitution:
$$P(\text{no event by time } t) = e^{-\lambda t}$$
And the CDF:
$$P(\text{no event by time } t) = 1 - F(t) = e^{-\lambda t}$$
Part 3: Next, I work towards defining this conditional distribution:
$$F(t) = P(\text{an event occurs by time } t)$$
$$1 - F(t) = P(\text{no event by time } t)$$
The probability of no event in the interval $[0, \Delta t]$. This is simply
$$1 - F(\Delta t)$$.
Putting it all together:
$$P(\text{no event in } \Delta t \text{ | no event at } 0) = \frac{P(\text{no event in } \Delta t \text{ AND no event at } 0)}{P(\text{no event at } 0)}$$
The numerator of this fraction is simply $1 - F(\Delta t)$, as this represents the probability of no event from time 0 to time $\Delta t$
The denominator is $1 - F(0)$, representing the probability of no event at time 0.
Therefore, we can write:
$$P(\text{no event in } \Delta t \text{ | no event at } 0) = \frac{1 - F(\Delta t)}{1 - F(0)}$$
Substituting real values into the above equation, we get:
$$ P(\text{no event in } \Delta t \text{ | no event at } 0) = \frac{1 - F(\Delta t)}{1 - F(0)} = \frac{e^{-\lambda \Delta t}}{e^{-\lambda \cdot 0}} = e^{-\lambda \Delta t}$$
Note that since we showed above that $P(\text{no event by time } 0) = 1$, this is the same as saying :
$$P(\text{no event in } \Delta t \text{ | no event at } 0) = P(\text{no event in } \Delta t) = 1 - \lambda \Delta t$$
Part 4:
We know the probability of no events happening in $\Delta t$:
$$ P(\text{no event in } \Delta t) = e^{-\lambda \Delta t} $$
Also, the probability of at least one event happening is the complement:
$$ P(\text{at least one event in } \Delta t) = 1 - e^{-\lambda \Delta t} $$
Now, we need to subtract the probability of two or more events happening. I struggle with this part theoretically, but loosely speaking, for small $\Delta t$, this probability is approximately $o(\Delta t)$, which means it's a term that approaches zero faster than $\Delta t$ as $\Delta t$ approaches zero.
Therefore, the probability of exactly one event in $\Delta t$ is:
$$ P(\text{exactly one event in } \Delta t) = (1 - e^{-\lambda \Delta t}) - o(\Delta t) $$
I have noticed that in such cases, we usually use a Taylor Series as a tool to show that certain parts of the equation are negligible. Expanding this using the Taylor series for $e^{-\lambda \Delta t}$:
$$ e^{-\lambda \Delta t} = 1 - \lambda \Delta t + \frac{(\lambda \Delta t)^2}{2!} - \frac{(\lambda \Delta t)^3}{3!} + ... $$
Substituting this back into our equation:
\begin{align}
P(\text{exactly one event in } \Delta t) 
&= 1 - \left(1 - \lambda \Delta t + \frac{(\lambda \Delta t)^2}{2!} - \frac{(\lambda \Delta t)^3}{3!} + \dots \right) - o(\Delta t) \\
&= \lambda \Delta t - \frac{(\lambda \Delta t)^2}{2!} + \frac{(\lambda \Delta t)^3}{3!} - \dots - o(\Delta t) \\
&= \lambda \Delta t - o_2 + o_3 - \dots - o(\Delta t)
\end{align}
For small $\Delta t$, we can approximate this as (the order terms disappear):
$$ P(\text{exactly one event in } \Delta t) \approx \lambda \Delta t $$
$$ P(\text{of no events in } \Delta t) \approx 1 - \lambda \Delta t $$
And this produces the desired result!
Is my calculus done more or less correctly?
References:

Opposite of a Poisson Distribution?
Necessary Assumptions when Deriving Poisson Distribution


If I were you I would not refrain from using the Poisson distribution to check my work: The probability of exactly one event in $[t,t+\Delta t]$ (being a small interval or not) is precisely
$$
\mathbb P\big{N_{t+\Delta t}-N_t=1\big}=\lambda\Delta t,e^{-\lambda\Delta t},.
$$
Does that help?
